# avrdude with usbasp and attiny2313 return errors

Tags: c, avrdude, attiny

I have problem with usbasp. Yesterday I work with device and change `CLKPR` register. After that something get trouble and now I get it:

```
]$ avrdude -c usbasp -p t2313 -v -F

avrdude.exe: Version 6.3-20190619
             Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
             Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

             System wide configuration file is "C:\dev\tools\avrdude\avrdude.conf"

             Using Port                    : usb
             Using Programmer              : usbasp
             AVR Part                      : ATtiny2313
             Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
             PAGEL                         : PD4
             BS2                           : PD6
             RESET disposition             : possible i/o
             RETRY pulse                   : SCK
             serial program mode           : yes
             parallel program mode         : yes
             Timeout                       : 200
             StabDelay                     : 100
             CmdexeDelay                   : 25
             SyncLoops                     : 32
             ByteDelay                     : 0
             PollIndex                     : 3
             PollValue                     : 0x53
             Memory Detail                 :

                                      Block Poll               Page                       Polled
               Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
               ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
               eeprom        65     6     4    0 no        128    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
               flash         65     6    32    0 yes      2048   32     64  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
               signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
               lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
               lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
               hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
               efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
               calibration    0     0     0    0 no          2    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

             Programmer Type : usbasp
             Description     : USBasp, http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/

avrdude.exe: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude.exe: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude.exe: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1
avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1
avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x320070
avrdude.exe: Expected signature for ATtiny2313 is 1E 91 0A

avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.
```

Actually, I have no idea what's problem. I check pins and restart Windows, but get this again and again. Thank you for your help. And yes, I install driver  for usbasp.

Comment: CLKPR modification should not lead to persistent changes. Default value should be loaded after reset. Probably you changed some fuse bits. Possibility and methods to recover depend on what bits are changed. What clock source is used in your device: internal oscillator, crystal, external clock? If you changed CLKSEL bits, you can try to program the IC with external clock source or crystal attached. Probably you'll need to play with avrdude's bitclock (`-B`). Also you can try to recover fuses with high-voltage parallel programmer. Or take another IC piece, if you have some.